# Cómo crear un evento con la api de google calendar desde PHP?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar

Estuve siguiendo paso a paso la configuración de la `api google` `calendar` para `PHP`, pero no se como utlizar el archivo para crear un evento, tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
  $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2016-03-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2016-03-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'pvieyra@itjvallereal.edu.mx'),
    array('email' => 'hfloresg@itjvallereal.edu.mx'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'pvieyra@itjvallereal.edu.mx';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Pero no se como mandar a llamar la clase `Google Service calendar`, estoy estancado en ese paso. Por ejemplo el `quickstart.php` que tiene la documentación sí corre, me devuelve los eventos que tenga creados en mi calendario.

Comment: Se puede saber donde defines la variable  $service?

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como pregunta Jose Javier, supongo que no estás llamando el servicio de calendario; Aún así, aquí dejo un ejemplo completo usando la librería 2.0.3.

```
$eventName = "Nombre del evento";
$eventDescription = "Descripción del evento";
$eventStartTime = "2016-11-01T13:00"; //Hora inicial del evento
$eventEndTime = "2016-11-01T14:00"; // //Hora final del evento

require_once "../../google-api-php-client-2.0.3/vendor/autoload.php";

$scopes = array(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig("client_credentials.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {    
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $eventName,
  'description' => $eventDescription,
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $eventStartTime.':00-06:00'

  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $eventEndTime.':00-06:00'
  ),  
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Favor de tomar nota que en este ejemplo no estoy especificando como poder autenticar al cliente. ¡Espero te sea de ayuda!